# Github Commit Check Fails

Tags: reactjs, github, vercel

I've been working on my portfolio for a while now, and after finishing I noticed that up to 5 commits back have failed all checks and it has a red X by the side of the commits, I have tried quite a number of solutions I saw online but to no avail. I need help as it is failing production deployment on Vercel.

https://github.com/busayolawumi/PersonalPortfolio - This is the github repository if you need to check it yourself

Comment: We're not able to view your Vercel build logs. Those logs are only available to your account. That said, I tried to build your project locally and ran into this error: `Could not resolve "../assets/selfie.png" from "src/sections/About.jsx"`. It appears to be a simple mistake with the image name. The file is named **Selfie.png** instead of **selfie.png**. Once I updated the import on this [line](https://github.com/busayolawumi/PersonalPortfolio/blob/main/src/sections/About.jsx#L2) to use `../assets/Selfie.png`, I was able to build your project.

Comment: @MattCarlotta Thanks, that totally solved it.

Comment: That's awesome, I'm glad I could help! By the way, if you'd like to receive faster responses to your questions, I'd suggest including the error and/or build logs within your question. This will make it easier for other developers to jump in and help out.